# Bootstrap muddling up when resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I alter my code so that resizing keeps everything within the window intact? As seen by the pictures, the text is outside the section when resized. Also, the image drops down in the navbar

any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Scrolling Nav - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">

                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button onclick="location.href='homenew.html'" class="dropbtn" >WATER</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="homenew.html#services">OUR MISSION</a>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="homenew.html#services">HELP US</a>
                  </div>
                </div>    

            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="team.html">Our Team</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="volunteering.html">Volunteer</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="contactus.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="donations.html">Donate</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <img class="alignright" src="icons/fundraisingbar.png">


            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>



    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 ">

            </div>s
                    <div class = "middle">
                         <h1 class="h1style offwhite">WATER2O</h1>
                         <h2 class="">mineral water</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "middle2 offwhite ">
                         <h2>H20</h2>
                         <h3>ALTERING  PERCEPTION </h2>
                    </div>


                    <div class ="animated bounceIn ">
                        <img class="arrowsize" src="http://www.under-water.co.uk/imgs/icons/tick-256x256-red.png">
                        <p class="whitetext">Registered</p>
                    </div>

    </section>
```

CSS

```
.icons{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.iconz{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.icontext{
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fundraise{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.offwhite{
    color: #EBE7E0;
}

.donation_amount{
    color: red;
}

.icons2{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.middle2{

    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0; 
}

.description_icon{
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.intro-section{
    background-color: black;
    /*background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9L6Aj0CJCuc/maxresdefault.jpg);*/
}

.main_text{
    color: white;
    top: 450px;
}

.logofirst{
    height: 300px;
    width: 450px;
}

.breadtext{
    color: white;
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-size:75px; 
}

.breadtext2{
    color: white;
    padding-left: 210px;
    font-size:30px; 
}

.footer1{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.arrowsize{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
}

.whitetext{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* Dropdown Button */
        .dropbtn {
            background-color: #F8F8F8;
            color: 777777;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        /* Links inside the dropdown */
        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
```

Comment: Can you make a snippet for the above code?? So that it could be easy to identify your problem..

Comment: @ManiRaj added CSS

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the CSS you currently have that's effecting the area?

Bootstrap has a feature for progress bars so you won't have to use a static image. You'll be then be able to change the width accordingly for the percentage you need the bar at.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
        <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit:

Alternatively you can just use @media queries in your CSS to reisze the width of the image dependant on the screen size that is being viewed at.